# Intent to recall activity error

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I made a layout xml for the settings of my app. I had a preference and I would like clicking on this will be sent to another activity. In the file of settings.java I put the following code to invoke the other activity but I get an error. This is the code:

```
Preference info;

info.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()) {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

How can i fix? Thanks

This is the error:

07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.XXX}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at com.XXX.onCreate(Impostazioni.java:56)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-03 14:43:46.314: E/AndroidRuntime(9691):     ... 11 more

Comment: what error you get put your logcat

Comment: I do not know because I can not run the project .. He says it contains errors

Comment: If you cannot build your project the console will often tell you which line contains the error and what might be the problem, post this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

you problem is here getBaseContext() 
replace it with :

```
     intent = new Intent(YourMainActivity.this, YourTargetedActivity.class);


     info.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() { 
     public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
     { 
     intent = new Intent(Impostazioni.this, Informazioni.class));
     startActivity(intent);
     return true;
     } 
     });
```

Comment: well, but now I get the error at the first line

// Error informazioni.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()) { // Error
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
 intent = new Intent(Impostazioni.this, Informazioni.class);
 startActivity(intent);

    }
}